# how do i get user input from the text fields and email on android?

Tags: java, android, class

hi i would like to know how i can setup the class file to get the user input from textfields and compose an email to be sent with a button?

example would be layout with fields

I want to buy ***_*__*_*_**
I want it to be this color ***_*__*_***
These are my comments ***_*___**

SEND BUTTON

and it should compose an email to specific email address with subject and add the fields on the email before sending.

hope someone would have a java code for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrt you creat your custom layout and make fields for what you want then these :

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@lol.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"" );
            this.startActivityt(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, ""));
```

Comment: thanks very much subspider.. will try this out and let you know the result..:)

Comment: please search first ok there are post of these [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577933/sending-an-email-using-user-input-from-android)

Comment: package com.emailmetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {
 Button send;
 TextView input1, input2;
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

Comment: package com.emailmetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {
 Button send;
 TextView input1, input2;
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

Comment: emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"myemail@hotmail.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"" );
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, ""));

    }
}

Answer (score 0):

i am sure on the following hint.but try this using GMailservices to send the mail

int patternMailCount=0;
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(toTextField.getText().toString(),",");
while(st.hasMoreElements()){
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+\-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st.nextToken().toString());

//...........

}
//ur implmentation

GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("yourgmail@gmail.com","your password");

sender.sendMail(
                                                                ""+((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SUBTEXTFIELD)).getText().toString(),
                                             emailID,toTextField.getText().toString());

Comment: i didn't know these one :D i will try